# xkeyboard-config: command not found and can't install it either

Tags: apt, xorg, 18.10

I am trying to set up Xpra on my headless Ubuntu server and in the process of trying to fix a problem I'm having (specifically, a `XKB: Could not invoke xkbcomp` error), I came across the advice that I should install and configure xkeyboard-config.

However, when I tried to run `xkeyboard-config`, the command was not found. I then tried to install `xkeyboard-config` but apt-get told me that `Package xkeyboard-config is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source`. I did find this which says that the package was deleted for Cosmic but doesn't mention alternatives:
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/cosmic/universe/proposed/xkeyboard-config

Can someone please help get xkeyboard-config installed and set up? Thanks.

---

Edit: I forgot to mention that right after the `XKB: Could not invoke xkbcomp` error, the Xorg log had the following line:
`Keyboard initialization failed. This could be a missing or incorrect setup of xkeyboard-config.`

This is why I am trying to see if there is something wrong with `xkeyboard-config` before I try other troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **source** package named `xkeyboard-config` is available in all Ubuntu releases:

1. see its page on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/cosmic/xkeyboard-config).
2. see output of locally ran `rmadison xkeyboard-config`:

```
$ rmadison xkeyboard-config
 xkeyboard-config | 2.5-1ubuntu1            | precise         | source
 xkeyboard-config | 2.5-1ubuntu1.5          | precise-updates | source
 xkeyboard-config | 2.10.1-1ubuntu1         | trusty          | source
 xkeyboard-config | 2.16-1ubuntu1           | xenial          | source
 xkeyboard-config | 2.23.1-1ubuntu1         | bionic          | source
 xkeyboard-config | 2.23.1-1ubuntu1         | cosmic          | source
 xkeyboard-config | 2.23.1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1 | bionic-proposed | source
 xkeyboard-config | 2.23.1-1ubuntu1.18.10.1 | cosmic-updates  | source
 xkeyboard-config | 2.23.1-1ubuntu1.18.10.1 | disco           | source
```

The following **binary** packages are built from this source package:

> **xkb-data**
>         X Keyboard Extension (XKB) configuration data
>   **xkb-data-i18n**
>         X Keyboard Extension (XKB) configuration data translations
>   **xkb-data-udeb**
>         X Keyboard Extension (XKB) configuration data

but they do not contain executables, only configuration data.

---

About your original problem with `xkbcomp` - [it is available from `x11-xkb-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xkbcomp&mode=exactfilename&suite=cosmic&arch=any) package. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-xkb-utils
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, `x11-xkb-utils` and `xkb-data` were automatically installed alongside Xorg so the problem is not them being missing. I've added some additional info about `xkeyboard-config` to the question.

Comment: Then you should edit your question again with complete steps you did with Xpra and so on. For me it is still too broad and indefinite.